usb stick reports write-protected but it's fine if I boot to it
I have a perfectly fine USB stick.  I used 'dd' to transfer a Debian 12 installation .iso file onto it.  It boots fine, and I can write to it with no issues.  However if I boot to a hard disk and then try to mount the USB stick:
4 /aWorking/Zsh/Source/Wk 1 % mount -rw -t auto /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/sdb is write-protected but explicit read-write mode requested.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

4 /aWorking/Zsh/Source/Wk 1 % hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)

4 /aWorking/Zsh/Source/Wk 1 % mount -rw -t auto /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/sdb is write-protected but explicit read-write mode requested.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

... is there anything I can do?  And no, there's no switch.  dmesg reports the thing is read-write.

Consider using ventoy instead with ventoy, you don't need to format the disk over and over, you just need to copy the ISO files to the USB drive and boot them directly.

If by "I can write to it with no issues" you mean that you can "write" to the live system from the live system itself, well that's expected as eveything is actually written to RAM; ISOs "flashed" onto USB devices usually have a ISO / UDF filesystem on them which isn't writable. You'll want to create a persistent ISO if you want to access files created during the live session after the fact.

I never did format the drive just used 'dd' to copy the image -- seems as simple as it could be.  But I can't mount it read-write from another boot.

How do I create a persistent ISO?

Hey kos, make that an answer so I can give it the green tick.  I know with a 'live CD' of course you can't write anything to the media, but I thought the usb would be different.
